# Replace part of a matched regex with sed

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a sample text which is a database output:

> objs/blabla   | Restore  | manual        | Restore Failed: **T**he volume
> does not want to exist         | BackupFailed            | 2020-10-
> 06**T**21:39:01 | 2020-10-06**T**21:39:01 | 0                    | 0                            | 0                                > | 0                                | 0

I need to change **only** the 'T' from the time/date string to a ',' (comma).

So far, I have tried:

```
sed -e 's/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/g' -e 's/T/,/g'
```

But it fails to isolate only the date time string, and produces the following output:

> objs/blabla   | Restore  | manual        | Restore Failed:,he volume
> does not want to exist         | BackupFailed            | 2020-10-
> 06,21:39:01 | 2020-10-06,21:39:01 | 0                    | 0                            | 0                                > | 0

Thus, it's also changing the 'The' to ',he' which is unwanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to match full date-time string. Following sed should work for you:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2})/\1,\2/g' file
```

```
objs/blabla | Restore | manual | Restore Failed: The volume does not want to exist | BackupFailed | 2020-10-06,21:39:01 | 2020-10-06,21:39:01 | 0 | 0 | 0 > | 0 | 0
```

**Details:**

- `([0-9]{2})` - Here we match 2 digits before and after `T` and capture them in group #1 and #2
- `\1,\2`: We put captured values back with `,` replacing `T`

---

As per OP's comments below, more fine grained regex that worked:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2})T([0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}){2})/\1,\3/g' file
```

Comment: awesome ! works, i'll acknowledge this best answer in 10 minutes. Thanks !

Comment: actually this matched some unwanted data: so i had to adapt it to my original case to match exactly the date format:

sed -E 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})/\1,\2/g'

Comment: Yes that's great, I am making that as part of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `awk` `gensub` option could you please try following.

```
awk -v regex="([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2})" '{$0=gensub(regex,"\\1,\\2", "g", $0)} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v regex="([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2})" '   ##Starting awk program from here, mentioning regex here to match 2 digits T 2 digits.
{
  $0=gensub(regex,"\\1,\\2", "g", $0)    ##using gensub to match the regex in current line and substitute 1st and 2nd matched part with comma globally in current line and save it into current line itself.
}
1                                        ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited line here.
' Input_file                             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```